# WebStorm configure output path for Sass

Tags: css, sass, output, webstorm, transpiler

I've a quick question about setting up a watcher in WebStorm for SCSS transpiling.

I want the watcher to transpile scss files to a specific folder:

`Project/assests/scss/(several scss files)`
transpile to
`Project/src/css/(transpiled css files)`

I noticed that there are terms like `$FileNameWithoutExtension$` or `$FileParentDir$`, what language is that? :)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try the following:

```
Arguments: --no-cache --update $FileName$:$ProjectFileDir$/src/css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css

Working directory: $FileDir$

Output paths to Refresh: $ProjectFileDir$/src/css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css:$ProjectFileDir$/src/css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css.map
```