# Can't get Sass compiler to output in other directory than the one app.sass resides in

Tags: sass, phpstorm

System: Windows 10 64bit, PhpStorm 2016.2 (the backslashes are not the problem, they are in the screenshot, but not in my actual code anymore)

This is my file structure

```
/css -> css files
/sass -> sass files
```

The `app.sass` is in the `/sass` directory, and when I change something there, the compiler automatically runs. But it puts the `app.css` and `app.css.map` in the `/sass` directory. Instead I like to have have it save to the `/css` directory.

This is my watcherTask.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="ProjectTasksOptions">
    <TaskOptions isEnabled="true">
      <option name="arguments" value="--no-cache --update $FileName$:$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css" />
      <option name="checkSyntaxErrors" value="true" />
      <option name="description" value="Compiles .sass files into .css files" />
      <option name="exitCodeBehavior" value="ERROR" />
      <option name="fileExtension" value="sass" />
      <option name="immediateSync" value="true" />
      <option name="name" value="Sass" />
      <option name="output" value="$FileParentDir$/css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css:$FileParentDir$/css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css.map" />
      <option name="outputFilters">
        <array />
      </option>
      <option name="outputFromStdout" value="false" />
      <option name="program" value="C:/Ruby22/bin/sass.bat" />
      <option name="scopeName" value="Project Files" />
      <option name="trackOnlyRoot" value="true" />
      <option name="workingDir" value="$FileDir$" />
      <envs />
    </TaskOptions>
  </component>
</project>
```

Any clue about what I am missing here?

Update: As requested, a screenshot of the watcher:
The field "output paths to refresh" corresponds to the "output" option.
The field "arguments" to the eh... arguments option.

[image: My file watcher]

Comment: Please show screenshot of your File Watcher -- it's easier to see your settings this way (visually). But so far -- you need to specify such paths in `Arguments` field

Comment: Okay, that's done :)

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36025976/webstorm-configure-output-path-for-sass

Comment: Hi, the field corresponds to the argument option in the above specified XML (I added a small legend on top of the screenshot).

Comment: Thanks, but I know what "output" fields (in both screenshot and xml file) do ... and they have **nothing** to do where generated files will be placed -- it is only for IDE to check what files to refresh after File Watcher has finished running (so it can also nest generated files under single node in Project View; so it can upload file to remote host if configured to do so etc)

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29096157/webstorm-scss-file-watcher-does-not-respect-parent-directory

Comment: So in short -- it should be something like `--no-cache --update $FileName$:$FileParentDir$/css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css`

Comment: I was just saying where the complete string could be found :) But the arguments options seems to have done the trick. It's a source -> target format, so that makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arguments option determines where the file source and target are:

```
--no-cache --update Source:Target
```

The default is

```
--no-cache --update $FileName$:$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css
```

which I then had to change to

```
--no-cache --update $FileName$:$FileParentDir$/css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css
```

This causes the system to save both the css and the css.map to the right folder.

Thanks @LazyOne for pointing this out.